# How to reduce the width of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

i am developing a website,in which i got a template for the website,i which the dropdown menu's width is full and how can i reduce the width to the size of the main heading.i have entered the code for the display page and the css script used in the html page is also entered below.please help to reduce the width of the dropdown menu to exact heading box size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Menu</title>
    <link href="ddmenu/ddmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="ddmenu/ddmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        /*The following are for this demo page only (not required for the ddmenu).*/
        body { background: #eee url(loginpage1.jpg) no-repeat center 0px; padding-top:90px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="ddmenu">

    <ul>
        <li class="full-width">
            <span class="top-heading">bguge</span>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><h3>hwehwieo</h3></li>
                        <li><a href='hgh.php'>gnehgiwe</a></li>
                        <li><a href='disuests.php'>ghgowgh</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <li class="full-width">
            <span class="top-heading">bgwegh</span>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><h3>ghurghoi</h3></li>
                        <li><a href="sasgru.php">ghg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="full-width">
            <span class="top-heading">hwegho</span>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><h3>UPDATES</h3></li>
                        <li><a href="updatestatusinput.php">REMARKS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">completed</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="full-width">
            <span class="top-heading">SEARCH</span>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><a href="termsimple.php">SEARCH</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li class="full-width">
            <span class="top-heading">APPROVALS</span>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><a href="aroval.php">PENDING APPROVALS</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="full-width">
           <li><a href="index.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
and the css scripts are 
#ddmenu
{
    display:block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center; /*Specify the alignment of the whole UL if UL is not width:100%;*/
    letter-spacing:normal;
}

#ddmenu ul
{ 
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center; /* Alignment of each top-level menu items within the UL */
    width:100%;
    font-size:0;
    background:#1C456E;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999999990; 
    max-width:1400px;
border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
border-radius:4px;
}

#ddmenu li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1; /*for IE6-7*/
    position:relative;
    color:#eee;
    line-height:46px; /*This determines the height of the menu*/
    vertical-align:middle;
    transition:background-color 0.2s;
    outline:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

#ddmenu .full-width {
    position: static;
}

#ddmenu .over
{
    color:#FFF;
background-color:#205081;
}

#ddmenu .over.no-sub {

}

#ddmenu .top-heading
{
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 16px;
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block; 
    outline:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* links of top-heading */
#ddmenu a, #ddmenu a:link, #ddmenu a:hover
{
    color:inherit;
}
#ddmenu a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#ddmenu a:focus
{
    outline:1px dotted #09F;
}

/* caret(arrow icon) */
#ddmenu .caret
{
    color:inherit;
    left:-12px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;/*for IE6*/
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-top: 4px solid;/*caret size is 4px now*/
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}  

/* sub-menu layout
----------------------------*/

#ddmenu .dropdown
{
    width:auto;    
    left:0px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0;margin:0;display:none;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;
    top:100%;
    border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
border-top:none;
border-radius:2px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
background-color:#ccc \9;/*fallback for old IE*/
}

#ddmenu .full-width .dropdown {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#ddmenu .offset300 {
    left:-300px;right:auto;
}

#ddmenu .right-aligned {
    left:auto;
    right:0px;
}

#ddmenu .over .dropdown
{
    display:block;
}

#ddmenu .dd-inner {
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:16px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:13px;
}

#ddmenu ul ul
{ 
    margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;width:auto;background:none;border:none;display:block;position:static;z-index:0;border-radius:0;
}

#ddmenu ul ul li
{
    font-size:13px;
    padding:6px 0; /*It determines the line height*/
    color:inherit;
    line-height:1;
    margin:0;display:block;position:static;background:none;border:none;transition:none;border-radius:0;
}

/* links in sub menu
----------------------------*/

#ddmenu .dropdown a
{
    color:#000;
    line-height:1;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:color 0.4s;
}

#ddmenu .dropdown a:hover, #ddmenu .dropdown a:focus
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#09F;
}

/* blocks within the sub-menu
-----------------------------*/
#ddmenu .column
{
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;/*or middle*/
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;*zoom:1;
    white-space:normal;
    width:auto;min-width:200px;
padding:0 30px;
border-right:1px solid #999;
}

#ddmenu .dd-inner ul:last-child
{
    border-right:none;
}

#ddmenu h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

    enter code here

#ddmenu div.column h3 {text-transform:uppercase;}

/* useful when http://www.menucool.com/ddmenu/one-menu-for-all-pages */
#ddmenuLink {display:none;}
```

Comment: I can see :  `width:100%;` in `#ddmenu ul` wouldn't it be this property ? you can try `width:33%;` and see if it changes

Comment: <li class="full-width"> might cause this

Answer (score 0):

```html
#ddmenu .full-width .dropdown {
    width:40%; // give width as per your need.
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```